# Starting a stopped EC2 instance with Boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I am writing a python script that starts a specific instance that is currently stopped, and I am kind of stumped on how I'd do that. As far as I can understand from the [Boto EC2 introduction](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ec2_tut.html#launching-instances) on launching instances this creates a completely new instance?

```
conn.run_instances(
    '<ami-image-id>',
    key_name='myKey',
    instance_type='c1.xlarge',
    security_groups=['your-security-group-here'])
```

Code examples would be very welcome!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had completely missed [this command in the API](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.instance.Instance.start)

For future reference, this is how to start a stopped instance:

```
instance = conn.get_all_instances(instance_ids=['instance_id'])
print instance[0].instances[0].start()
```

Comment: Looks like get_all_instances() has deprecated functionality and actually returns a list of Reservation objects. So it's more favorable to use:

`instances=conn.get_only_instances(instance_ids=['instance_id'])`

So that you can then:

`instances[0].start()`

Answer (score 4):

You can now start multiple instances in one `start_instances` call, e.g.:

```
conn.start_instances(instance_ids=['instance_id_1', 'instance_id_2',])
```

See http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.start_instances